# replacing comma with a <br> tag and set value of an html element

Tags: jquery

i am getting a string value in jQuery as for eg:- abc,bbc,ddd.
i having to replace comma with a 
 in html and have to set that string value to a textarea html element using jQuery.
Here is my code.

```
jQuery('input').on('change', function() {
  var filenames = Array.from(this.files).map(function(f) {
    return f.name;
  });
  console.log(filenames);
  jQuery("#selected-files").val(filenames);
  jQuery("#textarea-div").css("display", "block");
});
```

i am get filenames as abc,bbc,ddd.
this is the textarea code.

Comment: I can't see any attempt at replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filenamesWithBr = filenames.split(",").join("<br>");
```

This will give you a string with `,` replaced with `<br>`

You can also try replaceAll(), it didn't work when I tried.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: how can i set this filenamesWithBr value to textarea.i am displaying that textarea in on change function.now it is not showing when i add your code.